Analytical Method for Finding the Closest Point on a 3D Quadrilateral Polygon Face from a Line Segment
I am interested in developing an analytical method to determine the closest point on a convex quadrilateral polygon face, defined by four points (A, B, C, and D), from a given line segment connecting two points (P and Q) in 3D space. The quadrilateral polygon is assumed to be flat, meaning all its vertices (A, B, C, and D) lie in one single plane.
Specifically, I seek assistance in two aspects:

Algorithmically computing the point on the quadrilateral polygon that is nearest to the line segment.
Determining whether the line segment intersects with the quadrilateral polygon.

I prefer methods involving vectors or similar analytical approaches. It would be helpful to receive guidance on implementing such a method or references to relevant literature.
Moreover, I would appreciate insights into efficiently handling edge cases or alternative approaches.
EDIT: The current method that I am using is as follows.

Step 1: Find the rotation of the line segment within the ground coordinate frame.
Step 2: Rotate both the line segment and vectors connecting the edges of the polygon from one end of the line segment so that the line segment becomes parallel to the x-axis, and one end of the line segment has a coordinate of zero.
Step 3: Clip the vectors connecting the edges so that all vectors are within the region defined by the starting and ending points of the line segment.
Step 4: Find the intersection or closest point of the clipped polygon with the x-axis to determine the closest point.
Step 5: Rotate the obtained closest point back to its original orientation.


Are you currently using any particular method?

Given four points $\{p_i,\ i\in [1,4]\}$ the first step to do is to determine a sequence such that $\{p_1,p_2,p_3,p_4\}$ determine a convex region boundary: (we left this to the reader). Then choose
$$
\cases{
s_1(\lambda) = \lambda p_1+(1-\lambda)p_2\\
s_2(\lambda) = \lambda p_4+(1-\lambda)p_3\\
S(\lambda,\mu) = \mu s_1(\lambda)+(1-\mu)s_2(\lambda),\ \ (0\le \lambda\le 1),\ \ (0\le \mu\le 1)
}
$$
Now given the segment
$$
s_0(\gamma) = \gamma p_0+(1-\gamma)q_0,\ \ \ (0\le\gamma\le 1)
$$
we can formulate the minimization problem
$$
\{\lambda^*,\mu^*,\gamma^*\}=\arg\min_{\lambda,\mu,\gamma} \|S(\lambda,\mu) - s_0(\gamma)\|^2,\ \ \ \text{s. t.}\ \ \ \cases{0\le \lambda\le 1\\ 0\le \mu\le 1\\ 0\le\gamma\le 1}
$$
NOTE
The minimization procedure is standard involving a quadratic function with inf/sup restrictions.
Follows a MATHEMATICA script which implements the procedure.
p1 = {0, 0, 0};
p2 = {3, 0, 0};
p4 = {0, 1, 0};
p3 = {1, 2, 0};
s1[l_] := l p1 + (1 - l) p2;
s2[l_] := l p4 + (1 - l) p3;
q[l_, m_] := m s1[l] + (1 - m) s2[l]
p0 = {1, 0, 2};
q0 = {2, -1, 0};
s0 = n p0 + (1 - n) q0;
dist[l_, m_, n_] := (q[l, m] - s0) . (q[l, m] - s0)
gr0 = Graphics3D[{Red, PointSize[0.02], Point[{p1, p2, p3, p4}]}];
gr1 = Graphics3D[{Blue, PointSize[0.02], Point[{p0, q0}]}];
gr1a = ParametricPlot3D[s0, {n, 0, 1}];
sol = Minimize[{dist[l, m, n], 0 <= l <= 1, 0 <= m <= 1, 0 <= n <= 1}, {l, m, n}];
u1 = s0 /. sol[[2]];
u2 = q[l, m] /. sol[[2]];
gr3 = Graphics3D[{Black, PointSize[0.02], Point[{u1, u2}]}];
gr3a = ParametricPlot3D[a u1 + (1 - a) u2, {a, 0, 1}, PlotStyle -> {Dashed, Black}];
gr2 = ParametricPlot3D[q[l, m], {l, 0, 1}, {m, 0, 1}, Mesh -> {{0}}];
Show[gr0, gr1, gr1a, gr2, gr3, gr3a]



Thank you for the solution. However, I am seeking a direct analytical solution method without any optimization-based approach, as I will need to calculate the closest point multiple times (for instance, 100 times) within a single time step for a lengthy computation (for example, approximately 10,000 timesteps).

So what you have to do is walk on a graph that incorporates each and every possible solution.

I don't understand your idea. I am looking for a direct solution approach involving vectors, barycentric coordinates, etc.

This direct idea depends on a lot of if ... then ... else decisions. This is what I call "to walk in a graph" A lot of programming...
